# Simple jQuery function only returns a zero after for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables, for-loop

I have a jQuery function that I'm trying to use to ultimately make some text blink:

```
function blink() {

            var blinks = 7;
            blinks = blinks * 2; // Multiply by 2 to get an even number.
            var vis;

            for (i = 0; i < blinks; i++) {
                if (vis == 1) {
                    setTimeout(function () {

                        $("#ticker").animate({
                            opacity: 0
                        }, 0);
                        vis = 0;
                        alert(vis);

                    }, 500);
                } else {
                    //setTimeout(function () {

                    $("#ticker").animate({
                        opacity: 1
                    }, 0);
                    vis = 1;
                    alert("vis= " + vis);

                    //}, 500);
                }
            }

        }
```

Right now though, I'm just trying to get it return the correct number (1 or 0) depending on if the text is visible or not. If the text is on already then the function turns it off once, but then it stays off and even though I'm resetting the "vis" variable to indicate whether the text is visible or not. However, after the second iteration of the for loop, it only ever returns a zero for the vis variable. I am not sure what is causing this. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? I've been stuck on this for hours so any help you can give me would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are starting multiple async operations *all at the same time*. The loop finishes instantly, but the timeouts happen later.

Comment: Your for loop will be finished by the time that anonymous functions inside setTimeout are run.

Comment: So should I wrap the setTimeout around the for loop somehow?

Comment: As a design guideline, blinking text (which was in the original HTML browsers BTW) is a big no no :)

Comment: This is a huge amount of code to simply flash some text. Do you have an example of the HTML so we can mockup a nice demo?

Comment: Thanks @TrueBlueAussie. I'm aware of the history of blinking text in HTML and why it was removed. I know it's taboo in design classes but this is part of a larger project that I'm building that actually requires it.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie you simply have to wrap some text in a tag with id "ticker". This is all I have for the HTML side of things:
 <div id="ticker"> 
            Hi! This is a test of my latest ticker!
        </div>

Comment: Yep, that's pretty much what I added. Let us know if you need it to do anything different. setInterval is a simpler option than recursive use of setTimeout

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75310/discussion-between-digital-brent-and-trueblueaussie).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are starting multiple async operations *all at the same time*. The loop finishes instantly, but the timeouts happen later.

You can do it a lot simpler with an infinite timer that gets stopped and use `fadeToggle()` to fadein/out.

```
var count = 14;
var int = setInterval(function(){
    if (--count < 0){
        clearInterval(int);
    }
    $('#text').fadeToggle();
}, 500);
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/ev3b0das/

You can play around with the numbers and other options to try different effects (initial hide of the text etc)

If you do not want fading in/out use `toggle`:

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/ev3b0das/1/

and if you want the text visible at the end, make the count an odd number:

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/ev3b0das/2/

Answer (score 2):

Im not realy sure if i understad you correctly, but if i do, this would be my solution:

```
function blink(jquery_element, times) {
  if(times == 0) {
    return true;
  }
  // Toggle visibily once for hiding
  jquery_element.toggle(250, function() {
    // Toggle visibily again for showing
    jquery_element.toggle(250, function() {
      blink(jquery_element, --times);
    });
  });
  return true;
}
```

It's a recursive function that make the jquery element visible and hiding it as many times that was specified, would be used like this:

```
blink($("#ticker"), 7);
```

Answer (score 0):

I will not answer your question directly. Anyway, I want to share a method that I made some time ago to create a blink effect (using jQuery) and I think you can take advantage of it:

```
/**
  * @param {HTMLElement} $element
  * @param {Number} times Number of fade in/out times
  * @param {Number} [duration] Time of transitions in ms
  * @param {Function} [callback] Callback function to call after transitions
  */
var FadeEffect = function ($element, times, duration, callback) {
    if (typeof duration === "function") {
        callback = duration;
        duration = null;
    }
    else duration = duration || 250;
    for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        if (i === times - 1) $element.fadeOut(duration).fadeIn(duration, callback);
        else $element.fadeOut(duration).fadeIn(duration);
    }
};
```

Now, if you want, you can improve it to your requeriments. With this simple code you can solve your loop and async issues.

**edit:** [Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/g695jd1x/)

Answer (score 0):

For debugging, use the console, not `alert`. To show the console (Chrome, Firefox): `CTRL + MAJ + I`.
Your confusion is about synchronous versus asynchronous processing.

In order to understand, try to execute this wrong code then see the console:

```
function blink() {
    for (i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
        console.log('in the loop, i = ' + i);
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log('after timeout, i = ' + i);
        }, 500);
    }
}
```

A solution is to recursively call your function:

```
function blink(index) {
    if (index === undefined)
        index = 0;
    console.log('index = ' + index + ' ');
    if (index <= 6) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            blink(index + 1);
        }, 500);
    }
}
```

Comment: Aren't you missing something?